Who shuts down fake bayt din?
Who in the ancient Israelite justice system would be responsible for shutting down fake or rogue Bayt Dins doing things like fake conversions et al? (Before it reached the desk of the King.)

What do you mean by fake or rogue in this context? What would a fake conversion look like (a beth-din of הדיוטות can oversee conversion)?

A Beit Din of three unlearned Shomer Shabbat men is kosher for most purposes...what kind of a "fake" beit din are you asking about?

One's without a candidate. Like when someone takes a deceased person's ID in to get a mortgage or some government benefits.

@יהושעק I would imagine the best way to define a "rogue" Beit Din is one that a) doesn't work with other Beit Dins, especially higher ones and b) does dodgy things such as the examples in the question and maybe also c) indeed is composed of less-learned men

Less-learned men doesn't mean possul, @Rabbi Kaii, but a goniv is obviosly possul as an eid, let alone as a dayan

@יהושעק I see, I am defending rogue, you are questioning fake

A tricky question, do you ask about Rabbinic tradition or in reality? As we see from the Book of Ruth, each town and settlement had a court of its elders, the way it is still practiced in Arab and Bedouin villages in Palestine. Those courts were local and independent and their decisions were authoritative for the residents of that place. There can be no "fake " or rogue courts in such a system.
